# HMS Toolkit Conversion (G+H, HMS API 1st) Library (xmsadapter) Not Able to Import

Tags: android-studio, firebase-authentication, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am trying to port my app from GMS to (G+H) using HMS Toolkit.

After using the Toolkit Convertor, the following line throws an **unresolved reference error** on `import org.xms.f.auth.ExtensionAuth` asking to define xms. This obviously means the xmsadapter files (*which are generated by the HMS Toolkit Convertor*) have not been imported.

How can I fix this error to import the .xms files on `import org.xms.f.auth.ExtensionAuth` I feel like there's a dependancy that I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: Hi@KeagzB,Could you please provide with your version of the gms and hms? Let me check the info to see the problem.

Comment: @shirley Thank you for your response, can you please specify where I can find that information?

Comment: @shirley I have HMS Toolkit 5.3.0.301 installed

Comment: Hi@KeagzB,you can check the version of the gms and hms in [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/E4czM61VcBQjufd?format=png&name=4096x4096).After the conversion is complete using Toolkit, there is an xmsadapter folder, you can check it in README.

Comment: @shirley I have added the info in the question like you requested?

Comment: Hi@KeagzB,Could you please leave your email address？The R&D team wants to schedule a online video conference with you to locate the problem.

Comment: @shirley Lyndon.solomons@gmail.com

Comment: hi@KeagzB,The mail has been sent out to you,Please kindly check your email.

Comment: hi@KeagzB,i added my answer below,pls let me know if it worked. :D

Comment: The team confirms that you have been contacted and the issue has been resolved. NOTE: If you have any queries, please feel free to contact us. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also check your configured obfuscation scripts first.

XMS code generated using the Add HMS API policy will increase the size of your app. You can enable the code reduction function by adding or modifying the following configurations in the **app/build.gradle** file:

```
android {
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled true
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
}
```

If an error message such as **"Can't find..."**, **"NoClassDefFoundError"**, **"ClassNotFoundException"**, **"NoSuchFieldException"**, or **"NoSuchMethodException"** is displayed after minifyEnabled is set to true, configure the following XMS obfuscation rules in **app/proguard-rules.pro**:

```
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.hianalytics.android.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.updatesdk.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.hms.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}
-keep interface com.huawei.agconnect.**{*;}
-keep class com.huawei.hmf.**{*;}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.**{*;}
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.**{*;}

-keep class com.google.firebase.**{*;}
-keep interface com.google.firebase.**{*;}

-keep class org.xms.**{*;}
-keep interface org.xms.**{*;}
```

For details,you can refer to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/faq-0000001050061059#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050061059__section1648654845516).